# Some issues for the page load speed

Tags: performance

My English is not good and I find it really difficult to explain to everybody but please try to read it anyway.

I have a website with a big database. My site lost a lot of time to load page although google for 94/100 (https://developers.google.com/pagespeed/#url=5sonly.com_2Findex.php_3Fmain__page_3Dsearch_26keyword_3Dshirt_26slctbxsb_3D2_26slctbxshppngt_3D223_26page_3D132&mobile=false). I had optimized all content, database and used cache technology but time for the first byte is not good. Example:

When you try to click this link:

http://www.5sonly.com/index.php?main_page=search&keyword=shirt&slctbxsb=2&slctbxshppngt=223&page=132

You will have to wait a long time to the page load.

I had used index/fulltext for the search page but I dont know why my site is still very slow (more 24 seconds).

How can I do to optimize for the first byte time. I can provide all information if you request. Please let me know.

P/S: I have currently disabled cache to you can test better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing `heavy calculation at server side` so it responds slow,

you can see in image some `resource take 7 to 13 seconds to load`,

this cause your `loading slow`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replied.Yes you're right. I am running some cron jobs. I have tried to turn off them and recheck but nothing change

Comment: Please view this topic, thanks.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965656/optimize-speed-for-website